# Single metric to return multiple values

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I've recently upgraded from tensorflow v1 api into tensorflow v2 api and seem to be stumped by undesired behavior. I have a metric that returns an array which is valid in tensorflow v1. However, keras decides to combine my metric into a single value which is undesired behavior.

What I could do is call the same metric 6 times but I would assume it would be calculated 6 times independently which I would really like to avoid. Is there a way for keras to return all 6 values for the arrays, even an *n x 6* output would be preferred than this behavior.

```
def iou_loss(self):
    def model_quality(p, y):
        # brevity

        return [true_positive, false_positive, false_negative, completeness, correctness, quality]

    return model_quality
```

I want to calculate these metrics separately during `train` and `predict` phases.